# Chuck results from a query using model function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this code in my application :

```
$temoignages = $type->temoignages()->whereEtat('Actif')->get();
    foreach ($temoignages as $temoignage) {

        $str .= PHP_EOL.$temoignage['temoignage'].PHP_EOL.$temoignage->personne->prenom.' '.$temoignage->personne->nom;
    }
```

But I would like to get only 15 results from the query,.
I tried to used "chunk" but it's not working on objects apparently.

Can someone help me ? 
Thanks

Comment: so use take(15) after get,then it will take 15 row

Comment: @ImtiazPabel, you should use `take(15)` before `get()`, not after

Comment: thanks @AlexeyMezenin it was my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `take()`:

```
$temoignages = $type->temoignages()->whereEtat('Actif')->take(15)->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset